# Extract monthly NDVI (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel

I am currently writing code to extract a monthly NDVI for a specific polygon. I got the following code from a YouTube Tutorial and adapted it to my region and sensor. But it gets me the issue:

> roi.map is not a function.

What can I do?

Here is the code:

```js
// Extract monthly NDVI

// Define polygon
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [
              [152.52014194065384,-25.67552705424455],
              [152.5238272958403,-25.67552705424455],
              [152.5238272958403,-25.674115299750213],
              [152.52014194065384,-25.674115299750213],
              [152.52014194065384,-25.67552705424455]
            ]
          );

// NDVI function
var addNDVI = function(image){
  var nir = image.select('B8');
  var red = image.select('B4');
  var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI')
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}

// Monthly NDVI summary for polygon
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED")
                .map(addNDVI)
                .select('NDVI')
                .filterDate('2015-01-01','2016-12-31')
                .map(function(image){
                  var d = ee.Date(ee.Number(image.get('system:time_start')));
                  var m = ee.Number(d.get('month'));
                  var y = ee.Number(d.get('year'));
                  return image.set({'month':m,'year':y});
                })
                
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12)
var years = ee.List([2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022])

var byYearMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      years.map(function(y) {
        return months.map(function(m) {
          return sentinel2.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', y)
                          .filterMetadata('month', 'equals', m)
                          .select('NDVI').median()
                          .set('year', y)
                          .set('month', m)
                          .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1));
        });
      }).flatten()
    );

var proj = ee.Image(sentinel2.first()).projection()
   
var NDVI_roi = byYearMonth.map(function(image) {
  var features = roi.map(function(f) {
    return f.set('date', image.get('date'), 
                'month', image.get('month'),
                'year', image.get('year'));
  });
  return image.reduceRegions(features, ee.Reducer.median(), 250, proj); 
}).flatten();

print(NDVI_roi.limit(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

The roi needs to be a FeatureCollection but it was only a geometry in your current code. You can change it before using the `map()` function. To add NDVI, you don't need to create another function, you can easily do it with the `normalizedDifference()` function. The code has some issues that you will face after this correction.

1. You can set a filterBounds your roi for the overall imageCollection. Otherwise you can get a memory limit error.
2. Sentinel-2 images are available from 23 June 2015. You will not get previous images, if you mention previous dates in `filterDate().` It will throw an error.
3. The list of years should match the years mentioned in the `filterDate()`

I have modified the code addressing these points.

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [
              [152.52014194065384,-25.67552705424455],
              [152.5238272958403,-25.67552705424455],
              [152.5238272958403,-25.674115299750213],
              [152.52014194065384,-25.674115299750213],
              [152.52014194065384,-25.67552705424455]
            ]
          );


// Filter the Sentinel2 collection
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED")
                .filterDate('2016-01-01','2022-12-31')
                .filterBounds(roi)
                

// NDVI of all months
var NDVI = sentinel2.map(function(image){
                  var d = ee.Date(ee.Number(image.get('system:time_start')));
                  var m = ee.Number(d.get('month'));
                  var y = ee.Number(d.get('year'));
                  var ndvi=image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('NDVI')
                  return ndvi.set({'month':m,'year':y});
})      

var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12)
var years = ee.List.sequence(2016,2022)

var byYearMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      years.map(function(y) {
        return months.map(function(m) {
          return NDVI.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', y)
                          .filterMetadata('month', 'equals', m).select('NDVI').median()
                          .set('year', y)
                          .set('month', m)
                          .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1));
        });
      }).flatten()
    );

var proj = ee.Image(NDVI.first()).projection()
   
var NDVI_roi = byYearMonth.map(function(image) {
  var features = ee.FeatureCollection(roi).map(function(f) {
    return f.set('date', image.get('date'), 
                'month', image.get('month'),
                'year', image.get('year'));
  });
  return image.reduceRegions(features, ee.Reducer.median(), 250, proj); 
}).flatten();

print(NDVI_roi.limit(10));
```